# Consume JSON using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am developing a website which consume json from external url, i tried this but i got a error

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://reuniyo.com/tst/json.php. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Below is the code I used.

```
var url="http://reuniyo.com/tst/json.php";
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$("#success").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: See this link -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy this will explain your problem

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that the remote URL is not in the same domain as the web site you're developing, uou need to either:

1. use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) if the remote API supports it (my tests suggest that it doesn't)
2. have the remote site add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to their response headers

If neither of those are possible you're out of luck - these rules are in there to prevent cross-origin scripting attacks.

Comment: i make it work by using `jQuery.support.cors = true;` in javascript but its working only in IE8 :(

Answer (score 0):

Add this line att the top of `json.php`

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: i make it ready by `jQuery.support.cors = true;`  '$.getJSON("http://reuniyo.com/tst/json.php",function(datas){`
         ` $.each(datas.Data, function(i,Data){`
           ` content = '<p>' + Data.CurrentDistance + '</p>';`
           
          `  $(content).appendTo("#product_list");`
         ` });});`
But its only working in IE8, is der any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to develop direct from your local file system, it creates all kinds of permissions problems. Move your development site to an http server (you can install one locally if you like).

You also need to make sure that the host name you are accessing the site from has permission from reuniyo.com to make Ajax requests to it (using the aforementioned Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header).

Comment: I _think_ he's suggesting that the remote API is a third party site, and not the same as the one hosting the HTTP content.